# return value to erb value

Tags: html, ruby, erb

The following code is designed to work with sinatra to take in values from an ERB generated HTML page. It calls a fibonacci sequence generator and sends the input values from the HTML into the generator. That code then returns a sentence with the next 10 digits in the fibonacci sequence generated from the user inputs. I then want it to be able to pass that return value into an HTML ERB page.  I have tried many of the solutions on here and other sites and have yet to find one that fixes my problem.

**Main Code:**
file name: */projects/webhosted_custom_fibonacci_calculator.rb

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"
require_relative 'fibonacci_calculator.rb'
require "erb"


include Calculator


get '/' do
    redirect ("/calculate")
end

get '/calculate' do
    erb :calculator_form, :locals => {:calculator => session[:calculator]}
end

post '/calculate' do
    num1 = params['firstnum'].to_i
    num2 = params['secondnum'].to_i
    output = Calculator.run(num1, num2)
    redirect ("/results_form?results=#{output}")
end

get '/results_form' do
    erb :results_form, :locals => {:results => params[:results]}
end
```

**The calculator:**
File name: */projects/fibonacci_calculator.rb

```
module Calculator
  def run(arg1, arg2)
    number = [2]
    number[0] = arg1    # Takes in passed values 
    number[1] = arg2
    first_number = number[0].to_i    # Makes sure inputs are integer values 
    second_number = number[1].to_i
    storage = []
    calculate_next = 0
    usage_number_1 = 0
    usage_number_2 = 1


        storage[0] = first_number
        storage[1] = second_number

        for i in (0..8)
            usage_number_1 = storage[i].to_i
            usage_number_2 = storage[i+1].to_i
            calculate_next = usage_number_1 + usage_number_2
            storage.push(calculate_next)
        end

        return "The values are: #{storage}" # Return value works fine
  end

end
```

**Input form:**
File name: */projects/views/calculator_form.erb

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fibonacci Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to the Custom Fibonacci Sequence Calculator</h1>

        <form action="/calculate" method="POST">
            First Number: <input type="number" name="firstnum" id = "1stnum" ><br>
            Second Number: <input type="number" name="secondnum" id = "2ndnum"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Result form:**
File name: */projects/views/results_form.erb

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fibonacci Calculator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Results</h1>

        <form action="/result" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name = "results" id = "out" size = "200" maxlength="600">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** I get the return value and can bring up the results form but the return value is not passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass your output to `/results_form`

One way to achieve this:

```
post '/calculate' do
    num1 = params['firstnum'].to_i
    num2 = params['secondnum'].to_i
    @@output = Calculator.run(num1, num2)
    redirect "/results_form/"
end

get '/results_form/?' do 
    erb :results_form, :locals => {:results => @@output}
end
```

And in your result view:

```
<h1>Results</h1>
<h3><%= results %></h3>
```

If you surprise why you don't need the `<html>` & the `<Body>` tag it's because they are in the layout.erb, for the full source you may have a look at my bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/l33tname/fibonacci_calculator/src